# Android - Attempt to write in a readonly database when I open it readonly

Tags: android, sqlite

i don't understand this at all.
I try to open a db located in my SD card this way:

```
db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, 
           SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

But in that very line it throws this exception:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: attempt to write a readonly database

It doesen't happen in my other devices, just this one that has android 2.3.3

Comment: Where exactly does it throw the exception? On that one line of code in your question? Post a complete stacktrace.

Comment: Yes it throws it in that very line